# Curves to mesh texture painting not working

Tags: mesh, texturing, bezier-curves, texture-painting, color

I am having trouble painting this mesh - it's my first time doing such a thing and couldn't find a solution-
I made this "hair" with curves and  then i turned them into a mesh, then i export the UV MAP and tried to texture paint it but it is not working - it is only fully painting some places and i need each "hair" to be of a different color.

- The green ones are not in the same object- there are painted  with principled material

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kdEUIapKpSGLdqYgfWYTpYSMGBV_vVH3/view?usp=sharing
this is the link of the project if you wanna check :)

i flip normals already and it helped a little but it is still happening

thank you so muchh

[image]

Comment: when i use "fill tool" for texture painting it does not pixelate - but it turn everything in one color so it is not what i am looking for -

Answer (score 1):

The meshes have very bad topology- in this case the overlapping is causing the problem. So, you paint on the front faces (faces with normals outwards) but the back faces are flickering through.
[image]

Second image shows how it should be after regenerating the stripes with a clean topology:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!